# Close curly bracket is missing while inserting data in mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I'm inserting JSONObject to mysql by converting it into .toString(). But closed curly bracket is missing in DB.

Eg: JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

jsonObj.put("name", "Peter");

String data = jsonObj.toString();

Im inserting this string data to mysql text column but my data in DB will be like {"name":"Peter"   here closed curly brace is missing. Anyone know about this issue.

Comment: Are you using JSON_OBEJCT()?

    SQL > select json_object("name","Peter");
    +-----------------------------+
    | json_object("name","Peter") |
    +-----------------------------+
    | {"name": "Peter"}           |
   +-----------------------------+

Comment: No i'm inserting String after converting jsonObject.toString()

Comment: What language are you using? (e.g., for `jsonObject.toString()`) Please add that as a tag so people have a frame of reference for your question.